# Azure function not running for 10 minutes

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a azure function which is deployed in azure cloud and i am trying to run my function for 10 minutes(default is 5 mins). I have added **functionTimeout** as in this [url](https://buildazure.com/2017/08/17/azure-functions-extend-execution-timeout-past-5-minutes/), but still it is running only for 5 minutes and failing.

```
{

  "queues": {    
   "maxPollingInterval": 2000,    
   "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",    
   "batchSize": 16,    
   "maxDequeueCount": 5,    
   "newBatchThreshold": 8,    
   "functionTimeout": "00:10:00"    
 }

}
```

Comment: does setting also idleTimeoutInMinutes help?

Answer (score 1):

You should bring the **"functionTimeout": "00:10:00"** outside of the queues into the root of the Json. So it should read like below.

```
{

  "queues": {
    "maxPollingInterval": 2000,
    "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
    "batchSize": 16,
    "maxDequeueCount": 5,
    "newBatchThreshold": 8
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00"

}
```